# How can I disable the notifications prompt in Safari?

Tags: safari, notifications, macos, apns

Safari for Mavericks has a website notifications feature allowing sites to send push notifications.

I never want to be prompted for this.

How can I disable the prompt for all websites, forever?

[image: Safari 7 websites notification prompt]

Comment: Have you tried my proposed solution ?

Answer (score 30):

Since the release of Safari 7.0.3 Apple finally gives us an option to turn off safari notification prompts. To disable safari notifications go to Preferences within Safari. Click the Websites tab (notifications tab for older versions of safari) and uncheck "Allow websites to ask for permission to send push notifications". And voilà.

**Websites panel for current Safari (as of High Sierra):**

[image: disabling safari notification prompt in High Sierra]

**Panel for older versions of Safari:**

[image: disabling safari notification prompt older versions of safari]

**The explanation below is only valid for versions of Safari before 7.0.3**

Apple obviously forgot the option to disable the notification thing in Safari altogether when they added the feature. Anyway this works, but is not for the faint of heart. ** This is only for older Safari before Version 7.0.3 **

```
Stop Safari
Open Terminal
cd ~/Library/Safari
chmod 000 RemoteNotifications/
```

That's it. 
The chmod 000 just makes the directory RemoteNotifications inaccessible. To make it accessible again (and to re-enable notifications in Safari) just do the above again but use 755 instead of 000 in the chmod command.

As lined out in Renés comment below, it is also possible to change the access rights via Finder.

Comment: I'm now using this for quite some time. So far no problems.

Comment: This works. I didn't use the `chmod` command though, but went to the `RemoteNotifications` folder with Finder, opened the folder info (⌘-I), and changed the permissions of my own username to `Read only`. No more prompts and the notifications pane in Safari settings remains empty. Perfect.

Answer (score 4):

The proposed answer of chmod 000 RemoteNotifications does work, but unfortunately console is spewed with many failed attempts to access files in the directory.

The messages are all being logged by a process called SafariNotificationAgent which appears to be the single source of grief.  This process can be stopped entirely using:

```
launchctl remove com.apple.SafariNotificationAgent
```

OS updates might turn this back on, but I'd rather it not even be wasting system resources trying to access a folder for a feature that I never wanted in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Today in Safari 11, this is available in Safari preferences under "Websites" > "Notifications". The built-in help describes it simply:

> *Stop seeing notification permission requests in Safari:* Choose Safari > Preferences, click Websites, then click Notifications. Deselect “Allow websites to ask for permission to send push notifications.” From now on, when you visit a website that can send you notifications, you aren’t asked.

Answer (score 1):

```
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari CanPromptForPushNotifications -boolean NO
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way to do it. I am thinking of using a plugin to block this code from running. It seems to be related to window.safari.pushNotification.permission in source code.

Comment: It is possible. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to existing answers:

Maybe after some time the second part of the accepted answer is outdated. It didn't stop the process. I had to go to activity monitor to find the process in the file system.

So I ended doing

```
sudo tcsh
chmod 000 /usr/libexec/SafariNotificationAgent
```

Works perfectly so far. The process doesn't run anymore when I restart Safari.

Answer (score 0):

In Safari 11 you can find this setting here:

[image: Safari 11 Settings screenshot]

Answer (score -2):

I tried everything
but finally got this 
this is amazing and it worked
http://forums.adobe.com/message/5791174

Comment: The linked forum page does not answer the original question.

Comment: @itsafire Rather than simply stating a post is wrong, explaining _how_ it's wrong or confusing often helps others more than the simple vote. What you did was fine, but just as the post itself is too brief, your comment would work better if more detailed.

Comment: thanks @bmike: The forum page is addressing a problem concerning the installation of an Adobe product which fails because the process 'safarinotification' is running.

Answer (score -3):

Go to **System Preferences > Notifications > Safari**, and then disable it from there. This will disable notifications for Safari, but I don't know if the prompt will stop. You have some more settings in Safari itself, but that's more management.

Comment: This didn't address my question.

Comment: This does not answer the original question at all.