# Disable notification prompts Safari 10.1

Tags: safari, macos, notifications

I am trying to prevent notification prompts from various websites in Safari 10.1. In the past one could go `preferences > notifications` and uncheck `Allow websites to ask for permission to send push notifications`, as [pointed out in this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106422/how-can-i-disable-the-notifications-prompt-in-safari).

I still get notifications prompts from some websites **whether or not** that box is checked/unchecked...

Is this a bug with Safari or I am forced to `chmod` the remote notifications directory?

[image: notification prompt]