Safari on iOS automatically denies notifications
I was playing around earlier with website notifications, and I couldn't seem to get it to work. Notifications requesting permission always return denied. I have Notifications enabled in Safari → Advanced → Experimental features, but it's still happening. I also tried adding the app to the home screen by Share → Add To Home Screen, but it still returns "denied".
I also tried clearing the website data in Safari → Advanced → Website Data before doing all this, but it still doesn't work. It works on my Windows laptop. The website I am testing it with is https://push-notifications-demo.netlify.app/
iOS version: 16.7.8

Is "Allow websites to ask for permission..." enabled in Preferences->Websites->Notifications? Compare https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/106422/30895

It's on iPhone (iOS 16.7.8)

There are resources here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending-web-push-notifications-in-web-apps-and-browsers

I tested and it doesn't work for me either so the website must be doing something incorrect

@Ezekiel I made my own little plaything at https://kalila.xyz/sp/mini/ios-notifs.html. It follows all the guidelines in the document you posted, but it still returns denied.

i found out why. the website needed a 'manifest.json' file with "display" set to "standalone" or "fullscreen" to properly install as an app on the home screen.
